# how to add syntactic sugar to rails similar to collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, syntactic-sugar

How one can add syntactic sugar similar to rails "add to collection" << operator, i.e.

```
@object.collection << item
```

I was trying to do

```
class Object
  def collection<<(item)
    ...
  end
end
```

but it does not work. Optionally I would like to define my own "operators" on attributes.

Note - i am aware hot to use `def <<(value)` but it works for the whole object not for its attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@object.collection << item
```

Let's take this apart.

- `@object` - well, some object.
- `collection` - when `@object` is sent
  this message it returns something.
- `<<` - this message is sent to the
  object that was returned from the `collection` message.
- `item` -
  parameter to `<<` message.

### Example

```
class Foo
  def << val
    puts "someone pushed #{val} to me"
  end
end

class Bar
  def collection
    @foo ||= Foo.new
  end
end

b = Bar.new

b.collection << 'item'
# someone pushed item to me
```

By the way, these forms do the same thing and produce the same output.

```
b.collection << 'item'
b.send(:collection).send(:<<, 'item')
b.collection.<<('item')
b.collection.<< 'item'
```

Comment: Although I like your solution it is still a pity, that the def @object.collection=(value) is possible - the assignment is privileged operator :-)

Comment: It is so for a reason. Getter/setter is a common idiom. Half-method-half-operator is not :)

Comment: Still the add operator is so common in rails that i expected it to be easier to tweak. But i see the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible based on how Ruby works. You will need your collection method to return an object which has your custom `<<` method on it.

Comment: Well that's pretty much what I said, I just didn't use the word 'proxy' ;) Instead I said "an object which has your custom `<<` method on it". But I upvoted the other answer because it has more detail than I gave

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is a method of `Array`, so this works in plain Ruby:

```
def MyClass
  def initialize
    @collection = []
  end
  def collection
    @collection
  end
end

MyClass.new.collection << 'foo'
```

Comment: I do not want to just add to the collection - how would I add special behaviour like checking for duplicates etc?